# Workstation Turtlebot connection help

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I tell my computer to start my turtlebot I get the error turtlebot: unrecognized service

How can I get my computer to recognize my turtlebot it is running Unbuntu 12.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57598/workstation-turtlebot-connection-help/) by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume that you are running Groovy. TurtleBot start service (sudo service turtlebot start) no longer exists in Groovy and version of ubuntu does not matter. Follow the tutorials and have these ([1](http://answers.ros.org/question/56704/turtlebot-2-errors/)
[2](http://answers.ros.org/question/56704/turtlebot-2-errors/)
[3](http://answers.ros.org/question/56733/what-does-start-turtlebot-button-do/)) questions for reference and you can set it up pretty easily.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0